# Python collisions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have recently learned python and have a school project involving pygame, but we weren't taught much, anyways I have been trying to make a maze in which the player (the white square), collides with the red block (the endpoint) something happens (a task takes place as a result of the collision), but I have tried various things but nothing seems to be working (I am still VERY new to pygame). Well, thanks for any help, but bear in mind that i am a beginner an that there are probably many mistakes in my code

```
import pygame


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (50, 50, 255)
GREEN = (33,206,14)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREY = (43,44,61)


SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600



class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):



    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()


        #self.image = pygame.image.load("basketballsprite.png").convert()
        #self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.walls = None
    def changespeed(self, x, y):

        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):


        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.change_y


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:


            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

        #if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Endpoint, self.image,True):



class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()


        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREY)


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

class Endpoint(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):


        super().__init__()


        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])


pygame.display.set_caption('A "Little" Maze Game...')


all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()



wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
Endpoint_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

wall = Wall(0, 0, 10, 600)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(0, 590, 400, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(450, 590, 390, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(10, 0, 790, 10)

wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(30, 200, 85, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(790, 0, 10, 800)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(70, 0, 10, 80)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(390, 500, 10, 150)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(450, 500, 10, 150)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(790, 0, 10, 800)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(400, 600, 2000, 15)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

Endpoint = Endpoint(400, 590, 50, 15)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(Endpoint)

wall = Wall(35, 100, 50, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(100, 95, 10, 80)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(100, 10, 10, 65)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(130, 200, 10, 90)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(130, 225, 90, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(50, 100, 10, 45)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(10, 160, 40, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(300, 200, 10, 250)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(240, 260, 60, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)
'''
wall = Wall(x, y, width, height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(x, y, width, height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(x, y, width, height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(x, y, width, height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(x, y, width, height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)
'''
player = Player(34, 34)
player.walls = wall_list

all_sprite_list.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 2)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -2)
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player,Endpoint_list):
        exit()

    all_sprite_list.update()

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, [40, 40], 30)

    all_sprite_list.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You haven't actually explained what is wrong with your code. Clarify what your expected behavior is and what it is currently doing.

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with the code, i just want it so that if the player collides with the endpoint sprite a task occurs, as i mentioned before i have made numerous attempts at doing this but nothing seems to work. I know there needs to be an if statemet or pygame.spritecollide(), i just dont know how to do it, im honeslty very confused - meaning that i have deleted all collision code in hope that one of u guys could assist me

Comment: well for starters your code is very cluttered. try adding the sprite to its groups in `__init__`.

Comment: You have a triple quote `'''` in your example which shouldn't be there and some variables are missing.

Comment: sorry thats my fault, i'll fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the `Endpoint` instance to the `Endpoint_list` which you use for the collision detection. Also, don't use the same name for the instance and the class, otherwise you're overriding the class and can't create new instances anymore.

```
endpoint = Endpoint(400, 590, 50, 15)  # Just use a lowercase name for the instance.
all_sprite_list.add(endpoint)
Endpoint_list.add(endpoint)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) function.

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, endpoint):
    print('exit reached')
```

Or just the `colliderect` method of the rects:

```
if player.rect.colliderect(endpoint):
```

Comment: Thanks, but would this work: if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(endpoint, self.image,True):
           print ("it works")

Comment: I've added two alternatives. You could use `spritecollide` if you want, but have to add the endpoint to the `Endpoint_list` as well.

Comment: OMG... thanks sooo much, you have no idea how much this has helped me, thanks for all your help, and I hope you continue to help beginners like me

Comment: I've just noticed something funny that I haven't known before: You can obviously just pass a sprite instance to [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) instead of a rect and it seems to work correctly.